# Why window.onhashchange works in IE7 compatibility mode?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, hash

Can't understand why this code works in IE7?

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){...})
```

This code should failed because IE7 doesn't support window.onhashchange event.

Does it work because I use IE9 in browser mode IE7. Should this code work in IE7?

Comment: Why do you use `bind("hashchange")` to `window` object? Don't you mix with jQuery's `$(window).bind()`?

Comment: Thanks, it should be $(window).bind('hashchange').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting read in the morning brew this morning regarding the dangers of cross browser testing using ie browser modes!

http://blog.typekit.com/2013/03/14/the-dangers-of-cross-browser-testing-with-ie9s-browser-modes/

Using browser modes isn't a true reflection of the actual real IE version